# hashmap in android xml parsing

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, iterator, hashmap

I have to fetch the data from xml feed and display on android application.

my xml feed is looking like:

```
<root>
 <Categories>
  <Category name="Books">
   <Articles>
  <article articleid="4537" title="Android" />
  <article articleid="4560" title="Java" />
   <article articleid="4585" title="PHP" />
   <article articleid="4731" title="MySql" />
  </Articles>
 </Category>
  <Category name="Names">
   <Articles> 
      <article articleid="266" title="Dita" />
       <article articleid="268" title="Frieda" />
        <article articleid="269" title="Demi" />
        <article articleid="271" title="Shyamalan" />
          <article articleid="269" title="Krish" /></Articles>
         </Category>
          </Categories></root>
```

Here i have to display category name.also have to display the article title for belonging category.i wish to display the output is:

```
      Books

      Android  Java  PHP  MySql

     Names

     Dita  Frieda  Demi  Shyamalan Krish
```

I have using below code:

```
static final String KEY_TITLE = "Category";
   static final String KEY_ARTICLE = "article";
      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TITLE);
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ARTICLE);
                System.out.println(nl.getLength());
        // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            System.out.println(nl.getLength());
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>   ();
            map.put( KEY_TITLE,((Element)nl.item(i)).getAttribute("name"));
           for (int j = 0; j < nl1.getLength(); j++) {
              map.put( KEY_ARTICLE,((Element)nl1.item(j)).getAttribute("title"));
                }
           songsList.add(map);
          }
```

Here i have to run the app means the article title is displayed.but the article title is didn't display correctly.my current o/p is looking like below:

```
     Books

      Krish  Krish  

     Names

     Krish  Krish
```

The last article title is dispalyed on all categories.Why these error is occurring ??? please help me...how can i resolve these error ??? please provide me some ideas ???

**EDIT:**

I have changed my code like below:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      static final String URL = "xxx";

 static final String KEY_TITLE = "Category";
 static final String KEY_ARTICLE = "article";
 static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
 LazyAdapter adapter;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     final ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TITLE);
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ARTICLE);
        NodeList nl2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_IMAGE);
        System.out.println(nl.getLength());
        HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            String name = ((Element) nl.item(i)).getAttribute("name");
             populateMap(map, name, KEY_TITLE);

           for(int j = 0; j < nl1.getLength(); j++) {
                String title=((Element) nl1.item(j)).getAttribute("title");
                populateMap(map, title, KEY_ARTICLE);
                String url=((Element) nl2.item(j)).getAttribute("url");
                populateMap(map, url, KEY_IMAGE);
                } 
           songsList.add(map); 
       } 
    GridView list = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);
   private void populateMap(HashMap<String, List<String>> map, String value,
        String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     List<String> myList;
     if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
         myList = new ArrayList<String>();
         myList.add(value);
         map.put(key, myList);
     } else {
         myList = map.get(key);
         myList.add(value);
     }
```

Now i have to run the app means am getting the o/p like below:

```
[Books,Names]
[Android,Java,PHP,Mysql,Dita,Frieda,Demi,Shyamalan,Krish]  [Android,Java,PHP,Mysql,Dita,Frieda,Demi,Shyamalan,Krish]

[Books,Names]
[Android,Java,PHP,Mysql,Dita,Frieda,Demi,Shyamalan,Krish]  [Android,Java,PHP,Mysql,Dita,Frieda,Demi,Shyamalan,Krish]
```

pls provide me some idea to get the correct o/p(my needed design).

This is my LazyAdpter file :

```
         public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Activity activity;
            private ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>> data;
            private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
           public ImageLoader imageLoader;
          ListAdapter listViewAdapter;
            public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>> songsList) {
                   activity = a;
                  data = songsList;
                  inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
                }

        public int getCount() {
                    return data.size();
                   }

             public Object getItem(int position) {
              return position;
            }

         public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent, false);


                TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title); 
                Gallery listview = (Gallery) vi .findViewById(R.id.model);

            HashMap<String, List<String>> item = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
             item = data.get(position);
             title.setText(item.get(MainActivity.KEY_TITLE).toString());
                  listViewAdapter = new ListAdapter(activity, data);
                 listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
                     return vi;
            }
```

This is ListAdapter class:

```
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View vi = convertView;
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow,parent, false);
            TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            HashMap<String, List<String>> item = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            item = data.get(position);
        title.setText(item.get(MainActivity.KEY_ARTICLE).toString());
         return vi;
            }
```

Comment: Did my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738659/add-the-value-in-arrayliststring-liststring-in-hashmap-android helps you to solv this question?

Comment: Did you get this output from my posted code?

Comment: @Festus Tamakloe yes am getting these o/p from your answer

Comment: Is your project an opensource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String,List<String>> categoryToArticlesMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
NodeList categoryNd = doc.getElementsByTagName("Category");
for (int i = 0; i < categoryNd.getLength(); i++) 
{
    Element e = (Element) categoryNd.item(i);
    String categoryName = e.getAttribute("name"); 
    NodeList articlesNd = e.getElementsByTagName("Articles");
    Element e1 = (Element) articlesNd.item(0);
    NodeList articleNd = e1.getElementsByTagName("article");
    List<String> articles = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int j = 0; j < articleNd.getLength(); j++) {
        Element articleNode = (Element) articleNd.item(j);
        String articleName = articleNode.getAttribute("title");
        articles.add(articleName);
    }
    categoryToArticlesMap.put(categoryName, articles);
}
```

This will give you the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this line `map.put( KEY_ARTICLE,((Element)nl1.item(j)).getAttribute("title"));` you are over writing the previous value present in the map. Change `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList` to `ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>> songsList` and add each value to list and put it to the map.
Even if you do this you will get output as,

```
Books    
Android Java PHP MySQL Dita Frieda Demi Shyamalan Krish     
Names     
Android Java PHP MySQL Dita Frieda Demi Shyamalan Krish
```

To get the desired output, you should consider the nodelist for `article` under each `Category` instead of getting all the `article` tags in the document.

Comment: Why do you need `ArrayList<HashMap<String,List<String>>`? Is it enough if you use `Map<String,List<String>>` ?? You want your output like this? Books --> Android Java PHP MySQL and Names --> Dita Frieda Demi Shyamalan Krish , Am I right?

Comment: yes i want the o/p looking like  Books --> Android Java PHP MySQL and Names --> Dita Frieda Demi Shyamalan Krish ly...

Comment: u r ly said like  Change ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList to ArrayList<HashMap<String, List<String>>> songsList ..thats y i have wrote the code like above